# Why is my speech recognition function maxing out with filling in two inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

I have javascript speech recognition code that is supposed to go through and append itself to three input boxes. For some reason, when I go through and run the code, it only successfully works appending itself to 2/3 of the input boxes. What am I doing wrong? Is it a syntax issue? Thanks!

code:

```
<form class="texts" action="/care" id="careid" name="care" method="POST">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="what's your name?">
                      <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Where are you?">
                      <input type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="how can I help?">
                      <input id="buttonInput" class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
              $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].play();
                })

              $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].pause();
                })

              video = document.getElementById('video1');
              
              function record() {
                var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || SpeechRecognition();
                recognition.interimResults = true;
                recognition.lang = "en-US";

                recognition.start();
 
                recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                  console.log(event);
                  document.getElementById("name").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                }

                recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                    recognition.start();
                    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      document.getElementById("location").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                      recognition.end();
                  }
                }
                )
              
  
                recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                    recognition.start();
                    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      document.getElementById("state").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                  }
                }
                )
                //   // recognition.addEventListener("end", () => {
                //   //   window.location.pathname = '/care';
                //   //   document.care.submit();
                //   // });
                // })
              }
```